# Right click on touchpad produces left click

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics, dell-vostro

Description of problem:

I am using Dual boot OS having Windows 10 as primary OS and Ubuntu 16.04 as secondary OS in Dell Vostro 15 3568 laptop.

In Ubuntu,Clicking the right-click area on the touchpad produces a left-click (it is a clickpad, and the entire touchpad is clickable) but  it is working fine in Windows 10.

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Click on the right click area on the touchpad in Ubuntu.

Actual results:
Left click, eg. follows the link in browser.

Expected results:
Right click, eg. opens a context menu.

Additional info:

```
xinput --list actually shows two touchpad devices - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad and a "DELL0794:00 06CB:7F13":
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0794:00 06CB:7F13                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
  ...
```